# Solve $(2x - 1)y'' - 4xy' + 4y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's publicly available materials.  One problem set question asks us to first verify that $x$ is a solution to $(2x - 1)y'' - 4xy' + 4y = 0$ (with $2x > 1$) and then use this to find a second, linearly independent solution.

The verification piece, of course, is trivial, but I am stumbling on second part.  I know that, in general, given a solution $f$ of a second order ODE $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$, we can obtain a linearly independent solution $g$ via the formula
\begin{align}
g & = f\int\frac {e^{-P(x)}}{f^2}dx
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
P(x) = \int p(x)dx.
\end{align}
In this case we have
\begin{align}
P(x) & = -4\int \frac{x}{2x - 1}dx\\
& = -2x + \ln|2x -1|
\end{align}
which means that 
\begin{align}
g(x) & = x\int \frac{e^{-2x}}{x^2(2x - 1)}dx
\end{align}
which (at least according to Wolfram Alpha) requires an exponential integral to satisfy.  Indeed, plugging the original DE into Wolfram Alpha leads me to something called a Sturm-Liouville equation, an entity with which I am not (yet) familiar.  (Wolfram gives a different basis of solutions for the ODE as well--but I digress.)

On the other hand, I can see that $e^{2x}$ solves the differential equation--but I kind of stumbled on this fact, rather than using any (non-fuzzy) reasoning to obtain it.

There must be something obvious that I'm missing here--but I don't see it.

Comment: Why do you think that $x e^{2x}$ solves the equation?

Comment: And the first formula is also suspicious. Much better: you know that $x$ is a solution. Make a substitution $y=xv$, where $v$ is a know unknown function. You will end up with a simple separable equation.

Comment: @Artem -- whoops - typo.  I meant $e^{2x}$, as you derived.  I've edited the original question.

Comment: @Artem -- As for the first formula, my impression is that it follows from Abel's identity and the fact that $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{W(f,g)}{f^2}$ where $W(f,g)$ is the Wronskian of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: This may be true, but it is still excessive, there is no need to memorize this kind of formulas.

Comment: True enough.  I promise that I haven't memorized it--as a math hobbyist (as opposed to a panic-stricken student) I make it a point to memorize almost nothing.  (Age has its advantages...)  The question that's bothering me now is why the formula, excessive as it might be, isn't working.  I mean, a basis of solutions is clearly given by $\lbrace x, e^{2x}\rbrace$.  Since the formula should guarantee a solution linearly independent to $x$, the nasty integral should evaluate (I think) to something of the form $c_1x + c_2e^{2x}$.  Probably I'm making some computational error, but I can't find it.

Comment: Without carefully looking it seems to be somewhere a simple sign is missing. Look at my integral below, it is quite close to what you've written.

Comment: Even two typos: $P(x)=-2x-\log(2x-1)$, and then do not forget you need $-P(x)$ in the integral. Then everything works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full argument. But before: do not memorize unnecessary formulas.

So, you have your solution $y(x)=x$. Noe, look for a solution in the form $y(x)=u(x)x$. You should end up with
$$
u''+\frac{4x-2-4x^2}{2x^2-x}u'=0.
$$
Now, using $v=u'$ you have a separable equation for $v$. You should find that
$$
v(x)=e^{2x}\frac{2x-1}{x^2}\,.
$$
Hence 
$$
u(x)=\int v(x)dx=\frac{e^{2x}}{x}+C.
$$
Hence, finally, your second solution is simply
$$
y(x)=u(x)x=e^{2x},
$$
which can be checked by direct substitution.